# Google Sheets variable does not work, hardcode string does

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to call a http rest url using Google Sheets custom function.

**This works**

```
function getProductDetailsbyEAN(EANCode) {
  EANCode = '8901719255137'
  if (EANCode == undefined) {
    Logger.log("EANCode undefined") ;
    return "undefined EANCode"
  }

  //EANCode = "'" + EANCode + "'"
  Logger.log(EANCode)  
  var formData = {
    'gtins': [EANCode],
  };
  Logger.log(formData.toString())

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : { 'Authorization':'Bearer mysecuritycode', 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(formData)
  };
  var URL = "http://myurl"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
  response = response.toString() ;
  if (response.indexOf("returned code 404") != -1) {
    Logger.log("ResponseError");
    Logger.log(response) ;
    return "ResponseError" ;
  }
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response) ;
  var jsonResponseItems = jsonResponse['items']
  var jsonResponseZerothItem = jsonResponseItems[0] ;
  Logger.log(jsonResponseZerothItem) ;
  return jsonResponseZerothItem ;
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

But if I try to get this working via the parameter it does not, returns 404

**This does not work**

```
function getProductDetailsbyEAN(EANCode) {
  //EANCode = '8901719255137'
  if (EANCode == undefined) {
    Logger.log("EANCode undefined") ;
    return "undefined EANCode"
  }

  EANCode = "'" + EANCode + "'"
  Logger.log(EANCode)  
  var formData = {
    'gtins': [EANCode],
  };
  Logger.log(formData.toString())

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : { 'Authorization':'Bearer myscuritycode', 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(formData)
  };
  var URL = "http://myurl"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
  response = response.toString() ;
  if (response.indexOf("returned code 404") != -1) {
    Logger.log("ResponseError");
    Logger.log(response) ;
    return "ResponseError" ;
  }
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response) ;
  var jsonResponseItems = jsonResponse['items']
  var jsonResponseZerothItem = jsonResponseItems[0] ;
  Logger.log(jsonResponseZerothItem) ;
  return jsonResponseZerothItem ;
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

I am missing something really basic on parameter passing. Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your case, it seems that `EANCode` is required to be used as the string. So how about this modification?

Please modify the below script in your question as follows.

#### From:

```
EANCode = "'" + EANCode + "'"
```

#### To:

```
EANCode = EANCode.toString();
```

#### Note:

- `8901719255137` is less than `9007199254740991` which is [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). So I thought that you can use `EANCode.toString()`.
- From your question, I cannot confirm the method for calling `getProductDetailsbyEAN(EANCode)`. So if above modification was not the direct solution, can you provide the script for calling `getProductDetailsbyEAN(EANCode)`?

#### Reference:

- [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Bang on, thanks, I tried it and it worked, it was the exact same issue.